# the Title Game - the game for the title of winner or loser?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "the Title Game" as "the game in which competitors vie for the title (of being winner or loser)"? Am I on the right track?

> The College Football Champion Not in **the Title Game**
> The University of Connecticut led the way in shutting down its program in deference to coronavirus precautions. Most of the Huskies’ peers lacked the courage to do the same.

> Source: [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/01/04/sports/college-football-coronavirus.html?action=click&algo=use&block=editors_picks_recirc&fellback=false&imp_id=874747923&impression_id=906baeb0-503f-11eb-8817-bdaef376049d&index=0&pgtype=Article&region=footer&req_id=222334144&surface=home-featured&variant=2_use)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence "the Title Game" isn't really an established natural collocation in English (though it might sometimes be an alternative to non-capitalised *the title **match*** - the final match in a series, where the last two remaining competitors slug it out for the chance to win a tournament title).

But the cited example simply means that the University of Connecticut (identified as  "College Football Champion", because they often win inter-college football tournaments) is no longer going to participate in "title-chasing" competitive sport (which is somewhat colloquially / dismissively labelled a "game"). It's equivalent to...

> 1: *The University of Connecticut is **getting out of the "title" game***
> 2: *My sister is getting out of the dating game* (stops going out on dates)
> 3: *Netflix is getting out of the political game* (stop promoting political agendas)
> 4: *Warren Buffett is getting out of the newspaper game* (sell newspaper shares)

...where #1 just means they won't participate in potentially title-winning inter-college football matches in future. Just don't ask me why the hack writer thinks this is a "courageous" decision, (I assume ***the Huskies' peers*** means all the other college teams they *would* have played against, who apparently aren't brave enough to withdraw from competition in response to Covid).

---

Idiomatically, you'll often see this colloquial use of ***the XXX game*** used in conjunction with ***getting into / out of*** activities associated with XXX. OP's cited example features what looks like a "headlinese" title *(**The College Football Champion Not in the Title Game**)*, where we'd normally expect at least the verb ***is*** after the subject. And even that would be a bit terse for normal spoken English, where I'd expect *The College Football Champion **is pulling out of** "the Title Game"*.

And if it was ***me*** speaking, I'd probably sign "air quotes" round those final words!

Comment: would "a playoff game" be synonymous with "a title game"?

Comment: There is no "expression" here to ask about whether anything else is "synonymous". There's a bit of ***productive syntax***, whereby we can use the fixed-form ***the XXX game*** to refer (usually disparagingly) to "any and all activities associated with XXX*.